# RN: constructor vs no constructor with props for component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my `React Native 0.59` `App.js`, 2 props are passed into each component:

```
const data = this.props.navigation.state.params.data;
const EventWithSelf = (props) => (<Event {...props} myself={data.myself} token={data.result} />)
const NeweventWithSelf = (props) => (<NewEvent {...props} myself={data.myself} token={data.result} />)
```

Since there is `{...props}` passed in for other `props` which may be needed for the component, do I have to initialize the component explicitly with constructor and run `super(props)` like below?

```
export default class Event extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._isMounted = true;
      this.state = {
        activeEvents: [],
        user: this.props.myself,
        token: this.props.token,
      };

    };
     //more code
```

Or I can go without constructor like below as well:

```
export default class Event extends React.Component {

      state = {
        activeEvents: [],
        user: this.props.myself,
        token: this.props.token,
      };
      //more code.........
```

Without explicit constructor, where is the better place to initialize `this._isMounted = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a `constructor` in place for this case. You can do something like this:

```
export default class Event extends React.Component {

      state = {
        activeEvents: [],
        user: this.props.myself,
        token: this.props.token,
      }
      _isMounted = false
}
```